# How to add a property to existing class definition with default value in Weaviate?

Tags: weaviate

The documentation on how to update an existing class to add a new property is clear in Weaviate documentation: [REST - /v1/schema | Weaviate - vector database](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/api/rest/schema#add-a-property)

However, what if I wanted to **add a property with a default value** and make this skipped for vectorization. We will just use this property for extra filtering purposes. For example, I wanted to add a new property "status" with default value of "PUBLIC" - is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

no, it is not possible to specify a default value for a property in weaviate. I suggest making a feature request on their github repo for this. It sounds like a useful feature to have.

Comment: Duda from Weaviate here :)
We also answered it in out forums here: https://forum.weaviate.io/t/how-to-add-a-property-to-existing-class-definition-with-default-value/535

Comment: And definitelly a useful feature, @hsm207 ;)